# -101 malloc memory failed DUDA CON SDK DE ZKTeco

Tags: c#, .net, zkemkeeper

estoy usando un Access Control Panel C3200 SYSCA-2R-2D de ZKTeco-Access Pro y necesito integrar el sdk para agregar usuarios y tarjetas desde un programa en VB o C#. El sdk que estoy utilizando es el que está en la página de ZKTeco https://www.zkteco.com/en/download_catgory/46.html   ---  Standalone SDK 6.3.1.37( Include Pull SDK 2.2.0.219) a 32 bits.

Me puedo conectar con el dispositivo y obtener datos, lo que no puedo es crear usuarios y meter las tarjetas.

Según la documentación de ZKTeco éste es el diagrama de flujo a seguir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He creado un form para probar si se registran los usuarios y el código queda así:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace PruebaPanelControl
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    
    public zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass zk = new zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass();
    int idwErrorCode = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnConecta.Text == "Conectar")
        {
            if (zk.Connect_Net(txtIP.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text)))
            {
                btnConecta.Text = "Desconectar";
                btnConecta.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                if (zk.SetStrCardNumber("4118015390")==false) {
                    zk.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
                    MessageBox.Show("error: " + idwErrorCode);
                }
                if (zk.SSR_SetUserInfo(zk.MachineNumber, "666", "Damian", "Pass", 1, true) == false) //Aqui me avienta un error
                {
                    zk.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
                    MessageBox.Show("error: " + idwErrorCode);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                zk.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
                MessageBox.Show("error: " + idwErrorCode);
                btnConecta.Text = "Reintenta";
                btnConecta.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            zk.Disconnect();
            btnConecta.Text = "Conectar";
            btnConecta.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Logro conectarme y obtener Datos pero al momento de usar el metodo SSR_SetUserInfo me avienta el error: -101.
En la documentación de ZKTeco describe el error como:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que podría causar este error? alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Suena a problemas creando nuevas variables de trabajo en memoria. Se estará quedando sin memoria? Tendrá líos trabajando a 32 bits con algo que estés haciendo a 64?

Comment: Acabo de hacer una prueba con la dll de 64 bits y me sigue dando el mismo error. Tengo 16 de RAM jaja no se que más pueda ser.

Comment: Encontré el mismo error pero no pude resolverlo. ¿Encontraste alguna solución a esto? ¡Por favor guía!

Comment: Por un momento pensé "¿Cómo es que esta pregunta tiene -101 votos?" 